# Create a program without infinite loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have to create a program that adds all the numbers from 1 to n following an equation. Then I want to add the total for those iterations in the `total_bis` list and have it again ask the user for a number of iterations and recalculate them. Without going into an infinite loop (which is what is happening to me). When the user gives the order to finish, the program ends.

Thanks.

```
n_iteraciones = int(input('Especifique el numero de iteraciones:'))

total_bis = []
total = 0
for elem in range(1, n_iteraciones + 1):
    total += elem * (elem +1) /2
    total_bis.append(total)
    
print(f'total: {total} para {n_iteraciones} iteraciones')

while True:
    n_iteraciones != 0
    print(n_iteraciones)
    
    if n_iteraciones == 0:
        break

n = len(total_bis)
print(n)
```

Comment: Did you mean to move the `while True:` to the top of your program?

Comment: Once your `while` loop loops, you can never exit, because it's testing `n_iteraciones` which is loop-invariant (it never changes inside the loop).  So either change `n_iteraciones` inside the loop, or change the exit test.

Comment: Also, the line `n_iteraciones != 0` serves no purpose.  It compares `n_iteraciones` to `0`, checking for inequality, then discards the result of the comparison without using it.  So either change that line to something useful, or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask for the user input inside a loop. If the user selects <kbd>q</kbd> instead, the loop breaks:

```
while True:
    n_iteraciones = input("Especifique el numero de iteraciones (pulse q para salir): ")
    if n_iteraciones == "q":
        break

    total_bis = []
    total = 0
    for elem in range(1, int(n_iteraciones) + 1):
        total += elem * (elem + 1) / 2
        total_bis.append(total)

    print(f"total: {total} para {n_iteraciones} iteraciones")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
while True:

    total_bis = []
    total = 0
    n_iteraciones = int(input('Especifique el numero de iteraciones:'))

    if n_iteraciones != 0:
        for elem in range(1, n_iteraciones + 1):
            total += elem * (elem +1) /2
            total_bis.append(total)
        print(f'total: {total} para {n_iteraciones} iteraciones')
    else:
        break
```